# Virtual environment wrong python version on MacOS

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, virtualenv, pyenv

I am having an issue where the virtual python environment has a different version of python than the version it should based on the directory naming convention.

[image: IMAGE: VS Code showing the possible python version choices within the virtual environment]

I used pyenv to install 3.7.4 and set the global version to 3.7.4, but Visual Studio Code cannot find python 3.7.4 in the relevant virtual directory.

How can I either remove 3.8.2 completely or change the default python version in the environment?

Answer (score 1):

To let vscode detect newly added virtual environments. You need to reload vscode

1. Open "Command Palette"
2. Type keyword "reload window", choose "Developer: Reload Window"